# How to convert a String number Into a int value?

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, robotics, processing-lang

I want to convert a string into a int value. in my real code, I receive a string "Slider 255" the number after slider changes from 0 to 255, so I want a int value to be equal to that number. This is a small example of the code:

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myServo;


int val = 0;
String s = "";
void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  myServo.attach(9);
}

void loop() {
  while(BT.available() >0){
  s =  Serial.read(); // which wiil be a number between 0 and 255
  // So I want val to be = to ehatever the string is. So far I have try this but it doesn´t work.
  // first attempt # 1
  val = s:
  myServo.write(val); 

  // Second attempt # 2 
  Serial.println(s)
  val = Serial.read();
   myServo.write(val);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use the [parseInt method available to Serial](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ParseInt) like this

```
int val = Serial.parseInt()
```

But, you will have to be sure that the non-number part of the message ("Slider") has already been dealt with.

You could also put the data into an [arduino String Object and use it's toInt method](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringToInt), or put it in a [C style string and use the atoi method](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/).